# Monterey: SSH with hardware key only works once

Tags: homebrew, ssh, monterey

I'm having an issue using my hardware security key with SSH on Monterey. The Apple-included OpenSSH build seems not to support hardware keys at all, as I get an error message saying `Cannot load FIDO key <key> without provider`.

To fix this, I have installed OpenSSH 8.8 from Homebrew. The first time I SSH with my key, it works as expected; however, all subsequent attempts generate the following error:

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ED25519-SK <key> from agent: agent refused operation
<REDACTED>: Permission denied (publickey).
```

In order to fix it, I need to `killall ssh-agent` every time. I never had this problem on Big Sur, and I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting.

Looking a little deeper, whenever I run SSH, my Mac starts `/usr/bin/ssh-agent` and not my `/opt/homebrew/bin/ssh-agent`. Manually starting the Homebrew version of `ssh-agent` before running `ssh` does *not* fix this; the Mac still spawns the bundled `ssh-agent` so that both are running. It does this even when I explicitly run `/opt/homebrew/bin/ssh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried disabling the built-in agent? I found [a blog post](https://aditsachde.com/posts/yubikey-ssh/) that explains this:

```
launchctl disable user/$UID/com.openssh.ssh-agent
```

I haven't tried it, but maybe it helps.

Comment: I had to follow a little more from that blog post, but this wound up working for me. Strangely, subsequent logins don't show me the "Confirm user presence for key" message, but it's a lot more useful than before. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have been of help! I'm trying to move to MacOS, but this kind of issues are driving me nuts (why would they not support SK in the built-in SSH?? Maybe I'll just stay with my Linux…

Answer (score 1):

Use Homebrew's OpenSSH

```
$ brew install openssh
```

Once installed, you have to override the one in your PATH by putting the OpenSSH folder at the beginning of your PATH in your RC file like this

```
$ export PATH=$(brew --prefix openssh)/bin:$PATH
```

Once you've done that and you've sourced your `rc` file you should be able to generate your key

Tested on macOS Monterey and `OpenSSH_9.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022`